# Increase of Cantor's devil staircase functon

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Cantor's function has an arithmetical presentation given as follows.
     Express $x$ in base 3. 
     That is for
 $$
 x \mapsto \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac{a_k}{3^k}, \ \  a_k \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}
 $$
    we have the mapping
     \begin{equation}
 \label{eq:arithm}
 F: x \mapsto y = 
     \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac{a_k / 2}{2^k}, \ a_k \in \{ 0, 2 \}  \\
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{M-1} \frac{a_k / 2}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^M}, a_M = 1 \\
 \end{array} \right.
 \end{equation}
    The set of increase of the Cantor's function is the Cantor's ternary set. 
    That is,   $ \forall z \in C$ we have

$$
  z \mapsto \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac{a_k}{3^k}, \ \  a_k \in \{ 0,   2 \}
$$

***The question is as follows:***

> I am trying to establish if the following limit exist using $\epsilon-\delta$ approach:
>   $$
>  \left| \frac{F(h)}{h^\alpha} - 1 \right| < \epsilon
> $$
>   for $h<\delta$, $\alpha=\log 2/ \log 3$.

My attempt so far:

Choose $ \delta <1/3^n$. Then
$$
 \left| \frac{F(3^n h)}{ 2^n h^\alpha} - 1 \right| < \epsilon
$$

$$
 \left| \frac{F(3^n h) - h^\alpha }{ 2^n h^\alpha}  \right| < \epsilon
$$
However, I am stuck because there are no obvious other identities to use.